# Update Drush in Docker4drupal

Tags: drush, upgrading

I have to upgrade Drupal core to 8.4 with Composer. Drush version is 8.1.12.

I use Docker4drupal for my local development environment. How do I update Drush to 9 within my docker container setup, so I can upgrade Drupal to 8.4?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the default `wodby/drupal:8-7.1-3.3.2` container image, the drush launcher is already [installed](https://github.com/wodby/drupal-php/blob/3.3.1/7/Dockerfile#L5) in the PHP FPM container.

Thus, your next step is to update your Drupal 8 composer drush dependency via composer:

`composer require 'drush/drush:^9'`

When drush launcher executes under your web root it will pick up the version 9 that's installed in your `vendor` dir.